# NoMethodError - undefined method `now' for Watir::Time:Class

Tags: ruby, selenium, automation, watir

I get the following error anytime I try to interact with a Watir element.

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-6.0.1/lib/watir/wait/timer.rb:40:in `current_time': undefined method `now' for Watir::Time:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-6.0.1/lib/watir/wait/timer.rb:6:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-6.0.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:656:in `new'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-6.0.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:656:in `element_call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-6.0.1/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:114:in `click'
    from fund_cc.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

Here is my code:

```
require 'watir'
# require 'time'

b = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)#, :url => "http://localhost:9515")
b.goto "https://www.bankofamerica.com/"

contact_us= b.link(:text, "Contact Us")
contact_us.click
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed in version 6.0.2.

From [Titus Fortner on the Watir-General mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/watir-general/ht_lhI9RSuY):

> The latest version of Watir attempts to use monotomic time where
>   supported and it looks like we grabbed the wrong Time class for where
>   it is not supported.
>
> I just updated and pushed the fix to 6.0.2. You should be able to just
>   bundle update now.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this behavior.  You can monkey patch your gem locally by tweaking the `current_time` method in `/lib/watir/wait/timer.rb`:

```
def current_time
  ::Time.now.to_f  # was Time.now.to_f
end
```

And I'd suggest logging an issue on https://github.com/watir/watir/issues.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like it was fixed in an update, but I'll keep this in mind if I run into something similar.